# Obtaining an interface from the Filter Graph Manager in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, filtering, directshow

I am working with a multimedia application that plays back multiple videos simultaneously from a capture card. What I am trying to achieve is muting one or more streams of input individually without affecting global volume at application or system level.

My assumption is that there is an instance of the mpeg-2 demux filter for each stream of input. If so, we can access the properties of each instance to set the volume level (0 or normal).

Since the capture cards audio is routed into the demux, I am not sure if the DVD-DV audio filter is separate and can be controlled as a group of channels routing into the windows audio system.

Some digging around suggests using the [IBasicAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389532) but I am not sure how to retrieve an interface from the Filter Graph Manager. Here is what I get using GraphEdit:

[image: Filter Graph]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter Graph Manager's `IBasicAudio` implementation is nothing but simple forward of calls to first suitable filter implementing `IBasicAudio`. That is, it might work out well if you have one audio stream in the graph. Having two or more there, you will need to locate audio renderer filters and work with their `IBasicAudio`.

MSDN instructs you to always query through FGM, but this is a good advice in the only case when you have one audio feed/renderer.

> This interface is implemented on the Audio Renderer (WaveOut) filter and the DirectSound Renderer filter, but is exposed to applications through the Filter Graph Manager. Applications should always retrieve this interface from the Filter Graph Manager.

The very basic path of obtaining `IBasicAudio` is shown in `\Samples\Players\PlayWnd\MainForm.cs`:

```
  this.graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder) new FilterGraph();

  // [...]

  // Query for audio interfaces, which may not be relevant for video-only files
  this.basicAudio = this.graphBuilder as IBasicAudio;
```

This obtains the interface pointer through FGM, just as MSDN suggests. Works well in case of single audio stream in the graph.

Comment: The assumption so far is that each input stream will have it's own instance of the filter graph. The real problem is how to obtain the interface in code in the first place. I am rather new to this and cannot seem to find simple illustrative examples on how to query the FGM for my purposes. Some conceptual guidance would go a long way here. Could you point me to some elementary sources or examples? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about how to get `IBasicAudio` once you already hold `IGraphBuilder`?

Comment: No, I was struggling with IGraphFilter as well but finally worked it out. Thanks.